# How to use same URL for GET and POST with Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I wish to stick to the API best practices and hence want to use the same URL for getting and updating a resource. My GET implementation was like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userconfig/{userName}", 
     method = (RequestMethod.GET))
@ResponseBody
public String userPreferenceService(@PathVariable String userName) {
```

This works fine. 
When I try to implement the update method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userconfig/{userName}", 
    method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String userPreferenceUpdateService(@PathVariable String userName,
        @RequestBody UserPreference userPreference) {
```

I get a 404 on both the methods. I remember running into a similar issue a few years back when I used Spring for a web-service implementation but forgot what I was doing wrong then.
Any pointers would be great.

Comment: I was hitting the wrong URL :/

Comment: What do you want `RequestMethod.PUT` or `RequestMethod.POST` ?

Comment: share the URL u are trying to hit, need to understand if the call is correct.

Comment: looks good to me, I believe you have the problem on the client side

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring-WS. This is just a Spring MVC Rest controller. Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by M. Deinum; this has to do with Spring MVC. I once faced with such kind of need and what I did was from the .jsp file, I added a hidden field that changes the method name as shown below:

```
<form id="deleteForm" action="your/url/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
</form>
```

And this is what solved my problem. For more information on this I refer you to **Spring in Practice** by **Willie Wheeler** with **Joshua White** I read the book and they uses this kind of solution a lot.